# RMI Communication between different JVM

Tags: java, rmi

We have written an RMI client application in Java 1.5 and same was integrated with a RMI server having java version 1.5.

Now my server is updated to Java 1.7 but I want to use the same RMI client application which was compiled in Java 1.5 to integrate with new server?

On the new server the stubs are not changed/updated but they have just complied in Java 1.7.

OS: Sun-Solaris 10

Is it possible? Or is there any workaround to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That should work as-is unless you are serializing Swing classes, which is specifically warned against in the Javadoc, or other JDK classes whose signature has changed. I would just try it.